# Получить значение массива

Tags: php, массивы

Переносила приложение на новый сервер и заметила такую штуку: при использовании конструкции такого вида

```
$param=preg_split('/:/', 'имя:значение')[1];
```

возникает ошибка

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
```

если изменить конструкцию на

```
$param=preg_split('/:/', 'имя:значение');
$param = $param[1];
```

то ошибки нет и код отрабатывает правильно. 
На старом сервере первая конструкция отрабатывала без ошибок. И на новом сервере и на старом стоят Apache 2.2 + PHP 5.3.6.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие настройки сервера (думаю, что причина в них) могли вызвать такую реакцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> И на новом сервере и на старом стоят Apache 2.2 + PHP 5.3.6.

Это неправда

На старом сервере версия была по меньшей мере 5.4, и, как следствие, поддерживала [разыменование массивов](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration54.new-features.php)

Следует отметить, что 5.3.6 устарела и перестала поддерживаться десять лет назад, а 5.4 - восемь. И этот факт как бы намекает, что пора бы немного обновиться.

Comment: Проверила на старом сервере версию, вы правы, там стоит 5.4.0.